# that and where difference

Tags: conjunctions

Would you mind explaining me which one is the correct one in following sentences.

1. > The place **where** we held the dinner last time was small and smelly.
2. > The place **that** we held the dinner last time was small and smelly.

Comment: Generally, with places use "where". With things, "The food *that* they served there was really bad." and with people, "The person "who" ran the place could not cook anything well."

Comment: what about the place that i called home ? It should be the place where i called home ?

Comment: *home* is tricky because it has several meanings in context, for example "the physical house" vs. "the heart and soul of your family", etc. You might add another example sentence using "home" to your question so it can be addressed in answers.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.The place where we had dinner last time was small and smelly.
>   2.This is the place which/that I call "home".

Whenever you want to find out the proper conjunction, try to ask questions.

> 1.We had dinner. Where did we have dinner?
>
> 2. I call "home". What do I call "home"?

I hope you see the difference.